# Custom login form with Vaadin + Spring Security + Ldap

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, vaadin

I want to create a custom login page for my Vaadin application.

**MyUi.class**

```
@Theme("valo")
@SpringUI
@Widgetset("pl.warta.AppWidgetSet")
public class MyUI extends UI {

@Autowired
private SpringViewProvider ViewProvider;

@Override
protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
    final Navigator navigator = new Navigator(this, this);
    navigator.addProvider(ViewProvider);
    setNavigator(navigator);

}
}
```

**WebSecurityConfig.class**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll();
    }

    @Configuration
    protected static class AuthenticationConfiguration extends GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.ldapAuthentication().userDnPatterns("uid={0},ou=people").groupSearchBase("ou=groups").contextSource().ldif("classpath:test-server.ldif");
        }
    }
}
```

**SecuredView.class**

```
@SpringView(name = SecuredView.NAME)
@UIScope
public class SecuredView extends VerticalLayout implements View {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6937605817612926676L;

    public static final String NAME = "";

    @PostConstruct
    private void postConstruct() {

        setSizeFull();
        setSpacing(true);
        setMargin(true);

        addComponent(new Label("<h3>Secured View</h3>", ContentMode.HTML));
    }
    @Override
    public void enter(ViewChangeEvent event) {

    }
}
```

Can you show me sample implementation of LoginView.class to match my Spring Security configure? When i created a view with `NAME = "login"` I'm getting:

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Thu Sep 10 09:47:14 CEST 2015
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

However even if page will apear, i dont know how to inject security validation on button click.

What I have didn't mentioned - login with default form is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to create a working solution.

For everyone facing this problem i recommend to fallow this example: [security-sample-managed](https://github.com/peholmst/vaadin4spring/tree/master/samples/security-sample-managed)

The only one change you need to do (ofc except throwing out model and logic) is a modify `Application.java`:

```
@Configuration
static class AuthenticationConfiguration implements AuthenticationManagerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        //we need to put here ldap authentication, e.g.:
        auth.ldapAuthentication().userDnPatterns("CN={0},OU=Users").contextSource().url("ldap://my.ldap.server:port").managerDn("adminDn").managerPassword("adminPassword");

    }
}
```

Everything else is configured for Vaadin already. Enjoy.